# django migrations - get migrations from location on disk

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-migrations

I have a django project but i want to get the migrations from a different location (not the project itself). I tried to use the `MIGRATION_MODULES` in the settings page but i could only make it work with different in project modules. I want to be able to do something like this but with paths to the migration files per app.
I digged in the migration mechanism in django and found this code that loads the migrations:

```
# part of loader.py from django.db.migrations
@classmethod
def migrations_module(cls, app_label):
    if app_label in settings.MIGRATION_MODULES:
        return settings.MIGRATION_MODULES[app_label]
    else:
        app_package_name = apps.get_app_config(app_label).name
        return '%s.%s' % (app_package_name, MIGRATIONS_MODULE_NAME)

def load_disk(self):
    """
    Loads the migrations from all INSTALLED_APPS from disk.
    """
    self.disk_migrations = {}
    self.unmigrated_apps = set()
    self.migrated_apps = set()
    for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
        # Get the migrations module directory
        module_name = self.migrations_module(app_config.label)
        was_loaded = module_name in sys.modules
        try:
            module = import_module(module_name)
        except ImportError as e:
```

When i get to my module - it fails on the import_module line.
Is there any way to tell django the migration module location on disk instead of the module name?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to give Django just a path to your migration module. Migrations are actual Python modules, so they must be importable from some location in your `PYTHONPATH`.

You can of course change your `PYTHONPATH` so that the location on disk is importable in Python.